# Do i need to reindex the table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-performance

I have a table in mysql with a lot of INSERT and SELECT at every second. And there is a bulk delete of some older data once in a day. Do I need to reindex the table after delete? I want to increase the performance. Can anybody suggest some tips? Using 'innodb' as engine. Do I need to change it? I think its better for concurrent insert and select. pls give your suggestions. Do I need reindexing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Indexes update automatically after any change, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Barmar that's right, but after significant data modifications it makes sense to run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` that performs some servicing

Comment: @Friend: I have provided you the exact command keywords. What if you check the documentation first and ask a particular question if you have one **after**?

Comment: Cross-site [link to the same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82607/229525) asked on SE: Database Administrators, with relevant answers.